# Verify if list element method is called

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

How to verify if list element's method signature/s are invoked during unit test/s? For the code snippet below, how to verify if `item.getPrice()` was called when verify using `order` mock object?

Implementing code snippet:

```
public BigDecimal getTotalPrice(Order order) {
    BigDecimal totalPrice = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    for (Item item : order.getItems()) {
        totalPrice.add(item.getPrice());
    }

    return totalPrice;
}
```

Unit test code snippet:

```
@Test
public void testTotalPrice() {
    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
    for (BigDecimal price : prices) {
        Item item = mock(Item.class);
        when(item.getPrice()).thenReturn(price);

        items.add(item);
    }

    Order order = mock(Order.class);
    when(order.getItems()).thenReturn(items)

    BigDecimal totalPrice = orderHandler.getTotalPrice(order);
    verify(order, atLeastOnce()).getItems();
    verify(order.getItems().get(anyInt()), atLeastOnce()).getPrice();
    // assert
}
```

Test always getting failed, here the stacktrace (snippet);

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Misplaced argument matcher detected here:

-> // pointing to this line : verify(order.getItems().get(anyInt()), atLeastOnce()).getPrice();
```

What's the best way to implement this unit test scenario?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
//...other code removed for brevity
for (Item item : items) {
    verify(item, atLeastOnce()).getPrice();
}
```

Comment: Can't I really use `verify(order.getItems().get(anyInt()), atLeastOnce()).getPrice()` and result to verify element method in a for-loop? If so, why?

Comment: `order.getItems()` in the test is returning an actual list implementation (items) not a mock that is being watched and could be verified. The items in the list however are mocks and they can be verified.

Comment: That is also the reason for the `InvalidUseOfMatchersException`.  `anyInt()` is being applied to a concrete method.